# Defining facts within prolog rules

Tags: prolog

I am trying to translate the following statement into prolog:

"For all X, if X has a child who has a sister then X has two children."

I have defined the following rule:

```
has_two_children(X) :-
    parent(X,Y),
    sister(Y,_Z).
```

when I run it, I get:

```
"procedure `sister(A,B)' does not exist
 Reachable from:
      has_two_children(A)"
```

I have defined a parent relation separately, but I have not defined a sister relation separately. But this is puzzling to me. I was expecting it to just say false. What if no one i'm interested in has a sister? In that case, there's nothing I can put for the sister relation. Must I define the sister relation outside the rule?

Comment: Variable names such as Mother, Father, Sister, Brother would be easier to understand than X, Y, Z, A, B.

Comment: In what universe does having a child who has a sister mean there can't be another brother or sister? This is a flawed rule. What you should do is simply count them.

Comment: Sorry, are you talking to me? I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: "For all X, if X has a child who has a sister then X has two children" - this is illogical, families can have *more* than 2 children. Change it to: "For all parents, if Parent has a child who has a sister then Parent has *at least* 2 children". Better still, just count the Parent's children and return that value.

Comment: No, that isn't illogical because it doesn't say that X has only two children.

Comment: Then it is badly-named, at the very least. "has 2 children" means "has exactly 2 children", rather than "has at least 2 children, maybe more." What is the reason to have such a rule, what is its *use*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What if no one i'm interested in has a sister? In that case, there's nothing I can put for the sister relation.

You can put:

```
sister(_, _) :- false.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the sister relation in order for the has_two_children rule to work.